# Java - Creating a game. Kits, associating players and player-kit fields

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am attempting to create a game that involves kits that players can select. I've currently got a rather lengthy setup so I will try and condense this to what is necessary.

I have a **Kit** abstract class, which concrete kits extend, let's say for example, **Swordsman** and **Archer**. These classes have **no information about any players**, and as such, they only contain information about the kit itself such as the name, a description of the kit, a list of potential skills or abilities (This seems like an appropriate place to put this, though I'm unsure), etc. The idea is that at the start of each game, **only one** of each of these kits is instantiated and stored, and they are constantly referenced - for example, when a Kit Selection Menu of some sort is made, it will refer to these **Kit** objects.

When a player selects a kit and uses it, there may be fields specific to that player-kit instance. Say for example, an integer *shotsCount* that exists for each player that uses the **Archer** kit. Because I am only creating **one instance** of a kit per game, *shotsCount* cannot exist in the **Archer** class, as it will be shared across all players using the **Archer** kit (in a "global" manner?), as opposed to a **per player basis**.

On the other hand, if I were to create multiple kits for each player instance, as opposed to one per game, then if I want to only retrieve information about a kit without any player reference, then this wouldn't make much sense (The player reference in the kit class would be null?). As a result, I don't think this approach is correct.

Say, if I create a **PlayerKit** class that has this *shotsCount* variable, this wouldn't make much sense if the player were a **Swordsman**, as that variable is insignificant/irrelevant/doesn't exist for that kit (Swordsman doesn't have archery, and thus shouldn't have a *shotsCount* associated with them).

On the other hand, if I were to create separate classes for each player-kit instance, associating a player to their kit and the kit-specific stats for the player (for example, **PlayerSwordsman**, **PlayerArcher**, etc.), there would be many classes if there were a large number of kits added in the future, which may be unnecessary or redundant if many do not contain player-kit specific fields.​

I am wondering what the best approach to model this would be or if there are any suggestions regarding this. Are there useful design strategies or patterns for this? I hope I've explained this well enough to be understood. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand all your requirements correctly, you can look at the decorator:

Define classes for players:

```
abstract public class Player {
    public abstract int getShotsCount();
}

public class FirstPlayer extends Player {
    @Override
    public int getShotsCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Archer decorator definition:

```
public abstract class Kit extends Player // abstract class for decorator

public class ArcherKit extends Kit { // class for archer

    private Player player; // the decorator stores a link to the decorated object

    public ArcherKit(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public int getShotsCount() { 
        // for example, result depends on the player and the kit
        return 10 + player.getShotsCount();
        // or if (player instanceof FirstPlayer) ... 
    }
}
```

create a player with a kit of archer:

```
Player player = new ArcherKit(new FirstPlayer());
System.out.println("count = " + player.getShotsCount());
```

result:

```
count = 15
```

The "decorator" pattern dynamically gives an object new features and is a flexible alternative to subclassing in the field of expanding functionality.

But if there are many kits, this can complicate the architecture.

Comment: Interesting, I will look into the Decorator Pattern a bit more.

From what I see here, the getShotsCount() method exists in the Player class, which I believe means that it will exist regardless of which kit the player chooses. I think the issue still remains where if a player chooses a Swordsman kit for example, under your system the getShotsCount() method would still exist, and will essentially remain redundant/unused - Swordsman doesn't have access to archery, meaning that the getShotsCount wouldn't make sense for such a kit, yet the method still exists for that player.